# const member function apparently allows to change state of object

Tags: c++11

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int& cnt) : cnt_(cnt) {}
  void test() const
  {
    cnt_ = 0;
  }

protected:
  int& cnt_;
};

int cnt;
int main()
{
  Foo foo(cnt);
  foo.test();
}
```

The above code compiles. The test function is const, however we are allowed
to change the value of cnt_. If "cnt_" is not a reference then compiler
gives an error as expected. However if "cnt_" is a reference like above,
why doesn't compiler give an error ? We are still changing the state of the
object "Foo" inside a const member function, isn't it ?

Comment: `cnt_ = 0;` doesn't change the member, it changes the referenced object. That's just how references work. Same goes for `&cnt_` and `sizeof(cnt_)`, they all refer to the referenced object, not to the reference.

Answer (score 1):

The *member* `cnt_`, declared as:

```
int& cnt_;
```

is a *reference*, and inside the *member function*:

```
void test() const;
```

the `const`-qualification is applied to the *members*, i.e.: the *reference*, and not to the *object referenced*. Therefore, the object being referenced can still be modified through that reference, even inside a `const` member function, like the one above.

Note that, references can't be assigned after initialization anyway, so it really doesn't change what you can do with that reference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a pointer analogy will help.

Let's say you have:

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(int* cnt) : cnt_(cnt) {}

   void test1() const
   {
      *cnt_ = 0;
   }

   void test2(int* p) const
   {
      cnt_ = p; // Not allowed
   }

   int* cnt_;
};
```

In `test1`, you are not changing `cnt_`. You are changing the value of `cnt_` points to. That is allowed.

In `test2`, you are changing `cnt_`. That is not allowed.

In your case, you are not changing `cnt_` to reference another object. You are changing the value of the object `cnt_` references. Hence, it is allowed.